# How to enable server stack-trace for Rest calls in IBM Mobile First 8

Tags: java, rest, ibm-mobilefirst

In MF8, when I try to hit Rest Service URLs I am unable to get the stack trace when server returns a 500 error. I get the below error in POSTMAN.

```
"Unexpected error in server, see logs"
```

How can I enable the server stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear if you're using the devkit or the Mobile Foundation service.

Assuming you're using the devkit, you can find the logs in the devkit-folder/mfp-server/usr/servers/mfp/logs folder... there you will see a  messages.log file.

Comment: I am using mfdevkit and I am able to see the logs in log file. I want to see the stack trace in POSTMAN, if server is returning a 500 error. In MF 7, I was able to see the stack trace. Want to know if there are any config to enable the same?

Comment: so the client would get "Unexpected error in server, see logs", if the server  returns 500? Is there a way to enable it in server?